# pandas' fillna not working on resampled pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, fillna

I am working on `jupyter lab` with `pandas`, version `0.20.1`. I have a pivot table with a DatetimeIndex such as

```py
In [1]: 
pivot = df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns=['State'], values='B',
                       fill_value=0, aggfunc='count')
pivot

Out [1]:
State       SAFE  UNSAFE
Date                    
2017-11-18     1       0
2017-11-22    57      42
2017-11-23   155     223
```

The table counts all occurrences of events on a specific date, which can be either `SAFE` or `UNSAFE`. I need to resample the resulting table and sum the results.

Resampling the table with a daily frequency introduces `NaNs` on the days without data. Surprisingly, I cannot imput those `NaNs` with pandas' `fillna()`.

```py
In [2]: 
pivot = pivot.resample('D').sum().fillna(0.) 
pivot

Out [2]:
State        SAFE  UNSAFE
Date                     
2017-11-18    1.0     0.0
2017-11-19    NaN     NaN
2017-11-20    NaN     NaN
2017-11-21    NaN     NaN
2017-11-22   57.0    42.0
2017-11-23  155.0   223.0
```

Anyone can explain why this happens and how can I get rid of those `NaNs`? I could do something in the line of

```py
for col in ['SAFE', 'UNSAFE']:
    mov.loc[mov[col].isnull(), col] = 0
```

However that look rather ugly, plus I'd like to understand why the first approach is not working.

Comment: It works just fine for me (Pandas 0.21.0)

Comment: It is not working for me. Could it have something to do with how the original dataframe was created?

Comment: i was able to generate exactly the same DF as in your question and it worked fine for me...